# How can multiple html5 games be hosted in a server?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, heroku, html5-canvas, hosting

### Requirement

I'm am looking to host a website which contains **multiple html5 games**.
Similar to the [**Poki Games**](https://poki.com/), or any other web game platform.

### What I understand

I went through their (**Poki Games**) website and I found that multiple html5 game icons are listed on the website in a grid. And on clicking any one of the game icons, the website starts loading that particular game from an **external source inside an iframe**.

### What I Need answer on

I want to know how they are serving multiple html5 games from another domain. Since each of the games are loaded in a iFrame I'm aware that they all have their own index.html

How to achieve the same, what approaches should I take? So that if I do

```
<iframe src="//another.domain.com/randomHtml5Game_1">  // will load randomHtml5Game1 game
<iframe src="//another.domain.com/randomHtml5Game_2">  // will load randomHtml5Game2 game
```

### My skillset

I am primarily a frontend developer have experience with hosting in heroku. Also have some experience with firebase. I'll be using React along with phaser for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, the answer is very simple.

Just use code splitting and different render enpoints.

We would have our home page with various links to other pages (Image grid). When we click a image it changes the route.

```
www.domain.com/game1
www.domain.com/game2
www.domain.com/game3
```

You will need to code split the routes using various different ways. You could use webpack, or NextJS (Easier framework), or if your just using create-react-app, just use suspend and lazyload.

On a particular route it will load your html and javascript and run the game.

I am going to guess this isnt the answer your looking for but its a start ?

Let me know your thought ?

Daniel

Comment: What a coincidence!, I was looking up a video on nextJS. I'll have a go at it and see if it fits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports hosting multiple sites/domains using a single Project.
You could sepparate each game into a folder and host each of them separately and with a different domain.

You can find more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites).

I use this for example when deploying Web Apps. One domain is the app like app.appname.com then another domain [www.appname.com](http://www.appname.com) is the landing page and if the project as an REST API I host that under api.appname.com. In my case I just use different prefixes but the whole domain and url can be different.

The benefit is that if you use other Firebase features you can shared them between all those projects. For example the authentication or databases.

Comment: this also helps. The approach I'm using is combination of both Gadd and your answer. Thank you for making me aware of this firebase feature